# sql error while creating a table "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to create tables but an error is occurring at table ROUTE. I have no idea why. Can you point me the issue? thanks.

```
create table LOCATION (  
  airportCode   VARCHAR2(10) not null,  
  country       VARCHAR2(15) not null,  
  address       VARCHAR2(50) not null,  
  PRIMARY KEY(airportCode));

create table ROUTE (  
  routeID       VARCHAR2(10) not null,  
  airportCode   VARCHAR2(10) not null,  
  description   VARCHAR2(100) not null,  
  PRIMARY KEY(routeID, airportCode)
  FOREIGN KEY(airportCode) REFERENCES LOCATION(airportCode));
```

This error is coming, ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. all the parenthesis are correctly placed but still showing this error.

Comment: Missing comma between PK and FK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a , (comma) missing between `PRIMARY KEY(routeID, airportCode)`and `FOREIGN KEY(airportCode)`